# Mysql Query Optimization when using UNION ALL?

Tags: mysql

I wonder whether there is a better way to get the same result as below?

will running queries individually will cause better performance? or is there any way to run this query much faster with indexes?

```
SELECT count(*) as total FROM interests WHERE user_to='x' AND new='Y' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT count(*) as total FROM favorite WHERE user_to='x' AND new='Y' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT count(*) as total FROM view WHERE user_to='x' AND new='Y' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT count(*) as total FROM chat_msg WHERE to_user='x' AND received=0  
UNION ALL 
SELECT count(*) as total FROM mail_msg WHERE user_to='x' AND folder='1' AND new='Y'  
UNION ALL 
SELECT count(*) as total FROM user WHERE mode IN('active') AND (gender!='M') AND user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_from FROM block WHERE user_to='x') AND user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_from FROM block WHERE user_from='x') AND online=1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT count(*) as total_recent FROM users WHERE mode IN('active') AND (gender!='M') AND user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_from FROM block WHERE user_to='x') AND user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_from FROM block WHERE user_from='x') AND last_visit >= DATE_SUB('2020-2-12 14:19:24', INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Comment: What is purpose and expected output ?

Comment: 'will running queries individually will cause better performance' - nope that's effectively what you are doing.  'is there any way to run this query much faster with indexes?' - if you don't have indexes at all then I might expect performance improvement if you had them but knowing nothing of volumes it's hard to say. I would approach optimisation by running explains for each of the queries individually and adding indexes if necessary

Comment: Optimize each query separately. UNION ALL cannot be optimized - nothing to optimize. PS. How will you distinguish what subquery each count is taken from?

Comment: @jainvikram444 show some statistics to the user about his profile

Comment: @mahen3d Better way it's you will write a function and it's excute a query indivisual and finnaly total of all query result.

Comment: @jainvikram444 sole reason why i didn't do it, i thought if i do, i have to connect 5-6 times and query and then calculate ..which will add extra burden to the database than running one single query :(

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would give you a bunch of columns in one row (instead of a bunch of 1-column rows):

```
SELECT 
    ( SELECT count(*) as total FROM interests WHERE user_to='x' AND new='Y' ) AS Interests,
    ( SELECT count(*) as total FROM favorite WHERE user_to='x' AND new='Y' ) AS Favorites,
    ...;
```

You were not "connecting" each time; that would be extra overhead.  Several `SELECTs` is not that costly.

If those tables are "big", then the cost is in running each subquery.  Here are the necessary indexes, mostly 'composite' indexes:

```
interest, favorite, `view` :  (user_to, new)  -- in either order
chat_mag:  (to_user, received)  -- in either order
mail_msg:  (user_to, folder, new)  -- in any order
```

Longer discussion for these:

```
SELECT  count(*) as total
    FROM  user
    WHERE  mode IN('active')
      AND  (gender!='M')
      AND  user_id NOT IN (
        SELECT  user_from
            FROM  block
            WHERE  user_to='x'
                          )
      AND  user_id NOT IN (
        SELECT  user_from
            FROM  block
            WHERE  user_from='x'
                          )
      AND  online=1

SELECT  count(*) as total_recent
    FROM  users
    WHERE  mode IN('active')
      AND  (gender!='M')
      AND  user_id NOT IN (
        SELECT  user_from
            FROM  block
            WHERE  user_to='x'
                          )
      AND  user_id NOT IN (
        SELECT  user_from
            FROM  block
            WHERE  user_from='x'
                          )
      AND  last_visit >= DATE_SUB('2020-2-12 14:19:24', INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Some notes:

- How many `genders` are there?  `!=` cannot be indexed; `=` can.
- `NOT IN ( SELECT ... )` may perform poorly; consider `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL` or `NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 ... )`.  Depending on the MySQL version, one of these may be much faster than the others.

More indexes:

```
block: (user_to, user_from) and (user_from, user_to)
users: (active, gender, last_visit, user_id), (active, last_visit, user_id)
```